# Django Cart and Item Model - getting quantity to update

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views

I am working on a Django cart application. I have two models Cart and Item. I am trying to get the quantity to update when an Item is added to the basket but cant get the views to work properly. I am having problems getting item_obj assignment to work - do I need to do anything with the model manager here? Any help is really appreciated.

Models.py

```
class Cart(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, null=True, blank=True)
    products = models.ManyToManyField(Product, blank=True)
    total = models.DecimalField(default=0.00, max_digits=10, decimal_places=2)
    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    objects = CartManager()

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.id)

class Item(models.Model):
    item = models.ForeignKey(Product, null=True)
    cart = models.ForeignKey(Cart, null=True)
    quantity = models.PositiveIntegerField()
```

**Views.py extract**

```
    def cart_update(request):
        product_id = request.POST.get('product_id')
        product_obj = Item.objects.get(id=product_id)
        print(item_id)
        item_obj = Item.objects.get(id=product_id)
        cart_obj, new_obj = Cart.objects.new_or_get(request)
        if item_obj in cart_obj.products.all():
            cart_obj.products.add(product_obj)
            item_obj.quantity += 1
            item_obj.save()
        else:
            cart_obj.products.add(product_obj)
        return redirect("cart:home")

EDIT
```

Views.py update (12/02/2018)

```
def cart_update(request):
    # Based on the user who is making the request, grab the cart object
    cart_obj, new_obj = Cart.objects.new_or_get(request)
    # Get entries in the cart
    my_carts_current_entries = Entry.objects.filter(cart=cart_obj)
    # Get a list of your products
    products = Product.objects.all()

    if request.POST:
        # Get the product's ID from the POST request.
        product_id = request.POST.get('product_id')
        # Get the quantity of the product desired.
        product_quantity = request.POST.get('product_quantity')
        # Create the new Entry...this will update the cart on creation
        Entry.objects.create(cart=cart_obj, product=product_id, quantity=product_quantity)
        return HttpResponse('carts/carts.html')

    return render(request, 'carts/carts.html', {'cart_obj': cart_obj, 'my_carts_current_entries': my_carts_current_entries,
                                              'products': products})
```

Also I have a seperate model manager for the cart that creates a new cart or assigns one to the user, see below:

```
class CartManager(models.Manager):
    def new_or_get(self, request):
        cart_id = request.session.get("cart_id", None)
        qs = self.get_queryset().filter(id=cart_id)
        if qs.count() == 1:
            new_obj = False
            cart_obj = qs.first()
            if request.user.is_authenticated() and cart_obj.user is None:
                cart_obj.user = request.user
                cart_obj.save()
        else:
            cart_obj = Cart.objects.new(user=request.user)
            new_obj = True
            request.session['cart_id'] = cart_obj.id
        return cart_obj, new_obj


    def new(self, user=None):
        user_obj = None
        if user is not None:
            if user.is_authenticated():
                user_obj = user
        return self.model.objects.create(user=user_obj)
```

The error from the debug log is available here:

http://dpaste.com/1NX02JW

Thanks in advance

**Update 2:**

This is how my template file reads at the moment.

```
{% for product in cat_appetizers %}
<table>

<tr>   
<td><h5>{{ product.name }}</h5>
<td><p><strong>£ {{ product.price }}</strong></p></td>

<td>
    <form class='form-product-ajax' method="POST" action='{% url "cart:update" %}' data-endpoint='{% url "cart:update" %}' class="form"> {% csrf_token %}
        <input type="hidden" name='product_id' value='{{ product.id }}'>
        <span class='submit-span'>
        {% if product in cart.products.all %}
            <button>Remove</button>
        {% else %}
            <button>Add to Basket</button>
        </span>
        {% endif %}
    </form>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: what do you mean you are having problems getting the assignment to work?

Answer (score 7):

We can update the Cart model by using a [post-save signal](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/signals/) in the models. The following post-save receiver will update the Cart model any time an Entry is created.

### models.py

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.db import models
from django.db.models.signals import post_save
from django.dispatch import receiver
from django.utils.datetime_safe import datetime


class Product(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=64, unique=True)
    description = models.TextField(default='')
    cost = models.DecimalField(default=0.00, max_digits=10, decimal_places=2)


class Cart(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, null=True, blank=True, on_delete='CASCADE')
    count = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=0)
    total = models.DecimalField(default=0.00, max_digits=10, decimal_places=2)
    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return "User: {} has {} items in their cart. Their total is ${}".format(self.user, self.count, self.total)


class Entry(models.Model):
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product, null=True, on_delete='CASCADE')
    cart = models.ForeignKey(Cart, null=True, on_delete='CASCADE')
    quantity = models.PositiveIntegerField()

    def __str__(self):
        return "This entry contains {} {}(s).".format(self.quantity, self.product.name)


@receiver(post_save, sender=Entry)
def update_cart(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    line_cost = instance.quantity * instance.product.cost
    instance.cart.total += line_cost
    instance.cart.count += instance.quantity
    instance.cart.updated = datetime.now()
```

### Example Function

```
def test_my_cart():
    apple, created = Product.objects.get_or_create(name='apple', cost=0.25)
    my_cart, created = Cart.objects.get_or_create(user=None)

    print(my_cart)
    # STDOUT --> User: None has 0 items in their cart. Their total is $0.00
    entry1 = Entry.objects.create(product=apple, cart=my_cart, quantity=3)

    print(entry1)
    # STDOUT --> This entry contains 3 apple(s)
    print(my_cart)
    # STDOUT --> User: None has 3 items in their cart. Their total is $0.75
```

If you would like to remove the line entry from the cart at a later time there is also a post-delete signal in Django.

Best of luck

---

### Edit #1

To use this in the admin panel, try the [following](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.save_model):

```
# admin.py
from django.contrib import admin
from django.utils.datetime_safe import datetime

from app.models import Product, Cart, Entry


class EntryAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    # Overide of the save model
    def save_model(self, request, obj, form, change):
        obj.cart.total += obj.quantity * obj.product.cost
        obj.cart.count += obj.quantity
        obj.cart.updated = datetime.now()
        obj.cart.save()
        super().save_model(request, obj, form, change)

# Register your models here.
admin.site.register(Product)
admin.site.register(Cart)
admin.site.register(Entry, EntryAdmin)
```

I would also like to note that since there are "multiple ways to skin a cat" we could [override the save method in the model](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/models/#overriding-model-methods) instead of using the signal. I think this is dependent on application and personal preference though.

---

### Edit #2

This is an example view that will:

1. Get the User's cart
2. Grab the list of entries from that cart
3. Get a list of all unique names of products in those entries

#### example_view.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from scratchwork.models import Cart, Entry
from django.contrib.auth.models import User


def test_view(request):
    """ This view displays what is in a user's cart. """
    # Based on the user who is making the request, grab the cart object
    my_cart = Cart.objects.get_or_create(user=User)
    # Get a queryset of entries that correspond to "my_cart"
    list_of_entries = Entry.objects.filter(cart=my_cart)
    # Make a list of the product's names
    list_of_products = list(list_of_entries.values_list('product__name', flat=True))
    # Remove redundant product names
    list_of_products = list(set(list_of_products))
    return render(request, 'something.html', {'list_of_products': list_of_products})
```

---

### Edit #3

Before I talk about code, I'm going to do a quick comparison so we are on the same page concerning the model classes.

> Imagine you are shopping on Amazon. You as a Amazon customer have a
>   **Cart**. The cart will show you any **Entry** that you add to it while you are shopping on the site.
>
> As you go browsing the wondrous wares of Amazon you stumble across a
>   pair of shoes you want to buy. These shoes are a **Product** and have
>   a name, a price, and a description of the them.
>
> You decide to purchase these shoes so you click "Add to cart". At
>   this time the Amazon web service generates an **Entry** linked to the
>   **Cart** containing the information about the **Product**.

#### Implementation

So you are clicking a button to send POST data back to the view. Assuming you are either using a form or AJAX data to get the information back, this is how I would go about designing the view.

```
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.shortcuts import render
from scratchwork.models import Cart, Entry, Product
from django.contrib.auth.models import User


def test_view(request):
    # Based on the user who is making the request, grab the cart object
    my_cart = Cart.objects.get_or_create(user=User)
    # Get entries in the cart
    my_carts_current_entries = Entry.objects.filter(cart=my_cart)
    # Get a list of your products
    products = Product.objects.all()

    if request.POST:
        # Get the product's ID from the POST request.
        product_id = request.POST.get('product_id')
        # Get the object using our unique primary key
        product_obj = Product.objects.get(id=product_id)
        # Get the quantity of the product desired.
        product_quantity = request.POST.get('product_quantity')
        # Create the new Entry...this will update the cart on creation
        Entry.objects.create(cart=my_cart, product=product_obj, quantity=product_quantity)
        return HttpResponse('somewhereelse.html')

    return render(request, 'something.html', {'my_cart': my_cart, 'my_carts_current_entries': my_carts_current_entries,
                                              'products': products})
```

Comment: thanks but using django admin the cart doesn't actually update using the method above

Comment: Seems you are right. I just verified that my answer doen't update when using the admin panel. Are you updating the cart through the admin panel, the view, or both in you project?

Comment: Thanks, I will try this out and post feedback.

Comment: This now works via the admin app. How would I address the fact that my products are actually in my entry model. What would the view look like? For instance cart_obj.products.all is no longer valid since the products are not located in the carts model.

Comment: Because the entry model is now the link to the product and cart models, we  can grab our objects in a queryset from the entry. We then can grab a values list from that queryset. That list can be used to display the products in the cart.

Comment: My cart_update view actually executes when the HTML 'Add to Basket' is clicked. So I need the equivalent of cart_obj.products.add(product_obj) to work. I tried using list_of_entries.products.add but list_of_entries does not have a product attribute?

Comment: List of entries is a "Query Set" or grouping of model objects. Each model object in the Query Set has a property value, but as a group you can't directly grab that attribute. Set this [link](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/models/querysets/).

Comment: Thanks but I get an error: "Entry.product" must be a "Product" instance.

Comment: Please post the updated view and the debug printout.

Comment: I have updated the question to include these now. Please let me know. Thanks

Comment: Check example 3 again. I added an additional line to grab the object.

Comment: How does product_quantity = request.POST.get('product_quantity') work. Is this expecting to get the product quantity from the actual POST method - can we not set by retrieving it from the model instead?

Comment: It is expecting it from the POST. You are setting the value in the create. The model for the entry in question doesn't exist, so you can't get it there.

Comment: I am currently calling my product ID as per the description in Update 2. A little bit lost in terms of how I can call the product quantity within the form post.